# How to make this command work with all users

Tags: python, discord.py

guys my command only working for my bot, can someone help me?
to explain better:
*fake @mybot blabla (works)
*fake @SrWonka  blabla (dotn work)

Code:
Soucebin:https://sourceb.in/rkhH6YdTCx

```py
import discord
import re
from discord.ext import commands


class fake(commands.Cog):

    def _init_(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def fake(self, ctx, userid: str, *, message):
        await ctx.message.delete()
        userid = re.sub('[^0-9]', '', userid)
        webhooks = await ctx.message.channel.webhooks()
        noneWH = True
        server = ctx.message.guild
        for member in server.members:
            if member.id == int(userid):
                user = member
        for webhook in webhooks:
            if(webhook.name == "boteco"):
                if user.nick == None:
                    await webhook.send(content=message, username=user.name ,avatar_url=user.avatar_url)
                else:
                    await webhook.send(content=message, username=user.nick ,avatar_url=user.avatar_url)
                noneWH = False
        if noneWH:
            webhook = await ctx.message.channel.create_webhook(name="boteco")
            if user.nick == None:
                await webhook.send(content=message, username=user.name ,avatar_url=user.avatar_url)
            else:
                await webhook.send(content=message, username=user.nick ,avatar_url=user.avatar_url)

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(fake(client))
```

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/468304661951283223/869004359160193064/unknown.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed made:

- The way you were getting your user is not the optimal way I used `Typing.union` you can see the docs below.
- `display_name` it will show the nickname if there if not then it will show the username.
- `discord.utils.get` to get the webhook instead of looping

Here is the code edited:

```py
class fake(commands.Cog):

    def _init_(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def fake(self, ctx, user: typing.Union[discord.Member, discord.User], *, message):
        # await ctx.message.delete()
        webhooks = await ctx.message.channel.webhooks()

        # get the webhook if it is there
        webhook = discord.utils.get(webhooks, name="boteco")
        if webhook:
            await webhook.send(content=message, username=user.display_name, avatar_url=user.avatar_url)
        else:
            webhook = await ctx.message.channel.create_webhook(name="boteco")
            await webhook.send(content=message, username=user.display_name ,avatar_url=user.avatar_url)
```

First was for another user.

Second was for the bot itself.

[image]

Docs:

[`typing.union`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html?highlight=union#typing-union)

> A typing.Union is a special type hint that allows for the command to take in any of the specific types instead of a singular type.

[`Member.display_name`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=display_name#discord.Member.display_name)

> Returns the user’s display name.
> For regular users this is just their username, but if they have a guild specific nickname then that is returned instead.

[`discord.utils.get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get#discord.utils.get)

> A helper that returns the first element in the iterable that meets all the traits passed in attrs. This is an alternative for [`find().`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get#discord.utils.find)

Comment: thanks friend you're awesome, now works as expected and this docs will help in others parts of my bot

Comment: @MarcosSouza Glad to hear that, please mark at as an answer :)